# Rubber ducky windows mitigation

Tags: user-management, badusb

So I am familiar with badusb or rubber ducky attacks, I lack possession of one currently to test any of my questions.

Essentially my question is can you mitigate rubber ducky attacks using windows user privlages? for example putting users on a lower privilege account that can block access to the console, or admin privileges. My gut tells me yes, but I am not sure how trusted devices work out.

I have seen the duck hunt utility that can be used to mitigate ducky attacks, but assuming that is not an option will user access controls work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing two things up but I'll answer both:

1. UAC does not pose any mitigation to a rubber ducky or a teensy or any other platform. Next time a UAC dialog pops up, try pressing *CTRL + Y* and see what happens. They easily overcome UAC. Using UAC is meant to prevent software running on your pc from escalating privileges without your approval, but the pc considers you (or your 'keyboard') as approval.
2. As for granting a user low privileges - this *is* a mitigation, in the sense that the rubber ducky can only do what the user can, so the more you limit the user, the more you limit the duck. There is a trade-off here. For power users solutions like duckhunt are far better in my opinion but if this is a non-technical person's computer, then this is a great mitigation method.

**EDIT:** according to OPs comment and edit, my first point is irrelevant. I'm not removing it since I think anyone interested in HID attack mitigation should read this.

Comment: sorry, yes I mean user privileges not UAC.

Comment: @pacotaco Ok, I have edited my answer to focus more on that point.